# ScrollView does not scroll in fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, scrollview

I googled my problem and read similar questions in stackoverflow but I dont solve any way.

I have a layout with coordinatorLayout (main.xml) and a fragment with relativeLayout (fragment.xml)

> main.xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:text="FRAGMENT TITLE"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                    android:id="@+id/main_toolbar_title"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:background="@color/colorWhite"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp" />
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
```

> fragment.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="10dp"
android:background="#f3f3f3">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/card_view"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            card_view:contentPadding="1dp"
            card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp">

            <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="66dp"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:text="Button Title"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textColor="#404040"/>
                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="66dp"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:text="Button Title"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textColor="#404040"/>
                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="66dp"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:text="Button Title"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textColor="#404040"/>
                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="66dp"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:text="Button Title"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textColor="#404040"/>
                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="66dp"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:text="Button Title"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textColor="#404040"/>
                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="66dp"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:text="Button Title"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textColor="#404040"/>
                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="66dp"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:text="Button Title"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textColor="#404040"/>
                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="66dp"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:text="Button Title"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textColor="#404040"/>

            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

As you have seen, I have more buttons in scrollView but not scrolling. The ui elements in view pager, I first thought it was because of view pager but I have test it test_fragment.xml, it works perfectly.

scrollView scrolls when I press and hold out of view pager (ex. My First Tab)
 and move finger up/down

> test_fragment.xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
android:id="@+id/quickreturn_coordinator"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
```

What is the problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As your are working with `AppBarLayout`, it doesn't work with simple `ScrollView`. you should use `NestedScrollview` instead. and you have took your `ScrollView` inside `RelativeLayout` that's not necessary. try again with removing that `RelativeLayout` by using `NestedScrollView`.

I guess it will help.

Comment: Glad to hear that.. :)

Comment: Helped me fixing the issue, It was difficult to find the issue(AppBarLayout with scrollview), how did you identify this issue :)?

Comment: @Amritesh i am glad it helped.and about that issue, android Dev site has all Answers if we know know to find ;)